# Exporting 3d mesh obj file to unity5 has file size issue

Tags: google-project-tango

When i try to export 3d mesh .obj file from tango constructor to unity5 3d(https://developers.google.com/tango/tools/constructor#import_your_mesh_into_unity), it said "import fbx error". And there some people say this is file size problem. Because it is too big. (my .obj file is 120MB)

Is it really file size problem? if it is, how can i solve this issue? This 3d mesh is just room size.

Comment: What's the Unity error? Can you open the mesh with other 3d editor? maybe mesh lab?

Comment: i can open it with 3D builder. and 3dmac also. And unity error is, "import fbx error! can't import file." and there nothing in scene when i add this file to scene.